# The items you have selected cannot be shipped at the moment. Please contact the store owner to arrange for shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, magento-1.9.2.1

Each time I'm getting this error after completing order in my website. Order notification, payment all are working fine. But this message confused customers.

> The items you have selected cannot be shipped at the moment. Please
>   contact the store owner to arrange for shipping.

Anybody have any idea why this problem appearing and how to solve it? Here is the image [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string is not in Magento standard so it must be from an extension you installed. Navigate to the root directory of your magento installation and run this from the command line:

```
grep -r "The items you have selected" .
```

The filepath of the found file should show you which extension it's coming from. Contact the extension developer after that.

Comment: Brother you saved my time. It was from a shipping module. Just re-connected API issues of that module. Error gone thanks for help.